# Got input/output error in qbittorrent

Tags: windows-10, qbittorrent

Recently Ive upgraded from W7 to W10 (fresh install, not windows upgrade) and start getting endless problems with qbittorrent: "Input/output error occured for torrent". Ive several versions or another disk - same thing. Before I havent got any errors with that disk.

When I am trying to use bittorrent - everything is fine, so it must be some problem with qbittorrent. How could I fix it?

Comment: I had this before when I upgraded to win10. It ended up wrecking my 2tb hard drive. It was something to do with GPT or MBR partition style. Sorry I can't be more helpful (Its chosen when you format your drive and install windows)

Answer (score 2):

Dont know, what was the exact problem, but when I started qbittorrent with admin rights - there were no error.